# Django: DoesNotExist: SocialApp matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, twitter, django-socialauth

I'm trying to activate social logins in my Django web application, which comes from open source software in this [`GitHub repository`](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central) (so I didn't write it); and am running into this well-known issue:

```
DoesNotExist: SocialApp matching query does not exist.
```

The base `settings` file is located [`here`](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central/blob/master/biostar/settings/base.py). I do not modify that file at all. Instead, I `import` (inherit) it at the top of my `deploy.py` `settings` file, and make overrides and customization there.

Specifically related to this issue, here are the relevant overrides and additions that I made in `deploy.py` to enable **Google** and **Twitter** social authentication, both of which result in the same error:

```
INSTALLED_APPS.remove('allauth.socialaccount.providers.persona')  # Remove
INSTALLED_APPS.append('allauth.socialaccount.providers.google')   # Add
INSTALLED_APPS.append('allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter')  # Add

_GOOGLE = {
  'SCOPE': ['email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'],
  'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'},
  'PROVIDER_KEY': get_env("GOOGLE_PROVIDER_KEY"),                # Stored in secrets.env
  'PROVIDER_SECRET_KEY': get_env("GOOGLE_PROVIDER_SECRET_KEY"),  # Stored in secrets.env
}
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS['google'] = _GOOGLE # This isn't enabled in biostar.settings.base

_TWITTER = {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'},
        'PROVIDER_KEY': get_env("TWITTER_PROVIDER_KEY"),                # Stored in secrets.env
        'PROVIDER_SECRET_KEY': get_env("TWITTER_PROVIDER_SECRET_KEY"),  # Stored in secrets.env
}
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS['twitter'] = _TWITTER
```

I show two provider examples here -- **Twitter** and **Google** -- to show the *pattern* of what I am doing, and to show that the issue isn't provider-specific; though let's try to focus on just Twitter to keep things simple.

Now according to [`this document`](https://github.com/Bioconductor/support.bioconductor.org/blob/master/How_I_Setup_Biostar.txt) -- which comes from a [close fork](https://github.com/Bioconductor/support.bioconductor.org) of the above project -- in addition to what I implemented above (programmatically), it is necessary to also set up the same Social Accounts and the Keys/Secret-keys for them in the **Social Apps** section of the **Django Admin panel**. (Note that that fork was worked on by more-or-less the same team; so this requirement likely applies to the original upstream implementation, as well). The relevant part of that document instructs the following:

> After restoring, you need to re-enter social login info.
>   Unfortunately, even though this information is required to be in the config
>   environment that initializes biostar, it also requires it 
>   (redundantly) to be in the database as well. So go to the Django Admin panel
>   and click on Social Apps and then go through each app and fill in the
>   appropriate values.

So I went ahead and did that, too.

No matter what I try (*different providers, different keys, django panel additions, no django panel additions, etc*), I get the aforementioned exception, as though I'm missing a step.

Incidentally, I tried both key-pairs for Twitter (because I always forget which pair to use; so tried both `Consumer Key (API Key)` **+** `Consumer Secret (API Secret)` **and** `Access Token` **+** `Access Token Secret`, though it's really the former from what I read online). Just mentioning this for completeness.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Thank you in advance! :)

**EDIT-1**: Here is a full paste of the exception: https://pastebin.com/0UBAfAtu

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide full traceback instead of just `DoesNotExist: SocialApp matching query does not exist.`? The steps you have taken are good enough but full traceback will help in debugging the issue you are having.

Comment: Hi again @AamirAdnan I edited the question with a pastebin URL containing the information you requested. There are two back-to-back examples. (I regex'ed it to use example.com). You're correct: I should have included that originally. (._.)

Comment: When you have added the credentials for providers via admin panel in SocialApp, have you also selected the site (many to many rel) below to assign it to? https://imgur.com/a/lB5IY

Comment: I did. I used `example.com` and `www.example.com` (but with my domain instead). Is that what should be there (on the right-hand-side)? It's a good question because I didn't really know what exactly that was for. And still don't. Is that a protection mechanism?

Comment: Django has multiple sites framework. So when adding a provider in SocialApp you should tell on which site this provider can be used (could be multiple), you should select the site for which you/biostar has defined `SITE_ID` in settings file. I don't think of any other reason of failure instead of you are not selecting the correct site.

Comment: Hmm... `SITE_ID = 1` in `biostar.settings.base` (the basic settings file), and I haven't overridden that. I'll catch you on the other side. :). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error again and again and solve with this ..

The reason we get this error SITE_ID = 1
When "SocialApp matching query does not exist" occurs,

> this ID needs to be replaced.

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

hope for anyone else facing this issue will get help for this.

Comment: replaced with what?

Comment: Replaced with the correct id, check it in your model.

Answer (score 0):

**Following below steps will resolve this issue:**

1. Go to your database table named `django_site`.
2. Look at the id number of the site mentioned as a chosen site in the Social Applications.
3. Now configure `SITE_ID` to id number in setting.py of the Django project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and as people have said, you need to know the SITE_ID!

You have to make sure that on the Django admin dashboard, you have added your social application under SOCIAL ACCOUNTS.

When you're creating the social application, make sure that have listed the right websites for "chosen sites". If you're on local development, paste your computer IP in there. There will be a new SITE_ID associated with each "Chosen site" that you add to your application. Make sure you're using the right one that's associated to your IP. Personally, after adding my IP, I then just played and incremented my SITE_ID variable until it worked.

Posting this in case someone in a similar situation in the future lands on this page.